# ways to convert array to object in my case

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I face this problem a lots and I tired of writing conversion function

I can do

```
function toObject(arr) {
  var rv = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    rv[i] = arr[i];
  return rv;
}
```

but is there short-cut for that? my case as below :

```
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function(item){
    if(thread.checked === true){
        var links = item.url;
        chrome.tabs.create(links, function(tab) {

        });
    }
});
```

I'm using chrome API where links is obj :

```
chrome.tabs.create(obj, function(tab) {

});
```

Comment: Arrays are Objects. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In an ES5 browser you can do:

```
var obj = {};

[0,1,2].forEach(function(v, i){obj[i] = v});
```

or

```
[0,1,2].forEach(function(v, i, arr){this[i] = v}, obj);
```

As a function:

```
function toObj(arr) {
  var obj = {};
  arr.forEach(function(v, i){obj[i] = v});
  return obj;
}
```

If the object passed in may not be an array but an object with properties 0 to n, then:

```
function toObj(arr) {
  var obj = {};
  [].forEach.call(arr, function(v, i){obj[i] = v});
  return obj;
}
```